# Creating delimited values in one cell of data SQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I want to create a friends table where I have the userid of the current user, and the other userids of the current user's friends.

Kind of like this:

```
userid    friends
456       345; 745; 769;
```

I want to be able to update[insert the new value after the old] this data every time the current user gains a friends.

I've seen topics on delimiters and imploding/exploding data, but I can't seem to pinpoint how to start this.

any ideas, anyone?

Comment: I would start with adding another table that would group friendships as relations.

Comment: Storing data this way is not the most correct solution. Have you considered a `Friends` table with a foreign key? That way you will have on one table all the users with their data and a field pointing to the friends table with all the friends.

Comment: That is a *really* bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider your approach and use a simple table with one record for each userid/friends pair.

```
userid    friends
456       345
456       745
456       769
```

This way it's easy to select data from and to maintain.

Comment: But this will populate the table very easily, as I also have to add values the other way around. Anyhow, I'm just digging up ideas. Would your solution be the best one to implement? or is there any better idea to lessen he number of rows added?

Comment: You don't really have to care about row number. Do it when they come to millions! MySQL is really fast in handling these tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep existing structure. To add friends:

1. Check whether the friend exists in current friend list

Assume `$rs['friends']` contains `345; 745; 769;` and new friend ID is 999

```
// remove trailing `;`
$friend_list = substr($rs['friends'], 0, strlen($rs['friends'])-1);
$friends = explode('; ', $friend_list);
if(in_array(999, $friends)) {
  // friend exists
} else {
  $friend_list .= '; 999;';
  // then save back to DB
}
```

However, I recommend using relation table instead

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still learning. And all your opinions are really helpful.Thanks everyone! I'll consider each one and fish for more ideas.